# Page readable by file_get_contents but not cURL

Tags: php, json, api

I'm creating an API endpoint in PHP, and have a page that outputs JSON, let's call it `example.com/stats`. When a user tries to return the data, it's only successful when they use `file_get_contents()`, when users try to reach it using cURL they receive a NULL response. How should I be serving JSON data in PHP so that it's compatible with both file_get_contents and curl?

More info below.

**SOURCE for /stats**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '{"status":"error", "message":"invalid operation"}';
```

When I try to read this page from another server via `file_get_contents()` everything works fine.

```
function fgc($receive_url){
$fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($receive_url), true);
return $fgc;
}

$out = fgc("https://example.com/stats");
var_dump($out);

//returns: array(2) { ["status"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(17) "invalid operation" }
```

When I try doing the same thing but with cURL I get `NULL`.

```
function curlit($receive_url){
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $receive_url);
$ccc = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($ccc, true);
return $json;
}

$out = curlit("https://example.com/stats");
var_dump($out);
```

Please note other sites that display JSON work fine with my cURL function, it's specifically the data I'm serving from `example.com/stats` that fails when using cURL. I thought using the header application/json would be enough to allow this data to be reachable via cURL. Any ideas what could be wrong on the serving side? Why would file get contents work but not curl? Maybe cURL is displaying a result before the page is done loading? I tried removing the application/json header but that made no difference.

Comment: Is it an http or https URL?

Comment: HTTPS. SSL on `example.com` is active and enabled through cloudflare.

Comment: Can you try using the CLI version of cURL and see if that works?

Comment: Also, try adding this cURL option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: And if that doesn't work, just use `curl_error` to retrieve more information on which part is failing

Comment: I'm on windows, and don't have curl CLI. SSL_VERIFYPEER already set to false. curl_error returns `string(0)"" and curl_errno() returns 0`.  I also just tried adding curlopt_verbose and now it returns in browser 301 Moved Permanently and then gives a link to the endpoint. I'm wondering if this is because of htaccess rules I use strict_transport_security header with a 301 redirect?

Comment: Try making cURL follow the redirect by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: That worked!  So it's the 301 redirect... what do you think should I disable or just tell users to implement the followlocation curl opt? Thanks a million, by the way!

Comment: I'd just go with the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer added for reference:

After debuging with OP, he found out that `example.com` was issuing a 301 redirect.

Solution is to make cURL follow the redirect by adding the following option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server has disabled cURL, try to check it with `function_exists`:

```
var_dump(function_exists('curl_version'));
```

Comment: cURL is enabled, I'm able to reach other sites through this same cURL function.  It's specifically `example.com` that is returning NULL.